# python debugger pdb doesn't show command when typing (only shows dots in place of chars)

Tags: python, debugging, breakpoints, pdb, ddd-debugger

I was using the pdb debugger in the google colab https://colab.research.google.com/.

I was able to set a breakpoint at a line using pdb.set_trace(), but when the debugger stops there and I type-in the next command, it hides the typed characters in the command.

Shown below where "*********" appears in 'pdb' command line instead of 'p inputs' before the command executes:

[image]

How to fix this?

Why is pdb not showing characters in the command before it's run?

Comment: Hope you solved your issue eventually, which command were you using to access the `pdb` session?

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/689) discussion that suggests using `reset` or `stty sane`